# Trying to get location permission in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, core-location

I'm working on a button that will send the user to the maps application if he grants the app location permission. The problem is that if I click the button once and decline location permission, the next time I'm clicking the button the app doesn't ask for permission again. Seems like the user have "only one shot at granting maps permission".

Below is the code I use to programmatically create the button with the callback functions. There's also a screenshot of the "Custom iOS Target Properties" where I have included the Privacy - Location Usage Description to be able to use users location.

```
directionsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getDirection), for:   UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


func getDirection(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("1")
    if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways){
       let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=60.79281049999999,10.688968899999963")
       if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
        print("2")
    } else{
        LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        print("3")
    }
    print("4")
}

/*
 - Callback function for changes in location permissions
 */
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
    print("change in auth")
    if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse){
        let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=60.79281049999999,10.688968899999963")
        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    } else{
        self.view.makeToast("Couldn't get location permission", duration: 3.0, position: .bottom)
    }
}
```

[Picture of permissions added in the info-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bNEZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Seems like the user have "only one shot at granting maps permission".

Yes that is the case with the location permission, as it is for other things such as address book access permission.
Your app could detect that the user has refused permission previously, and if so tell them they need to enable it via settings with a button called something like "Take me to settings" or whatever.
On button click you can launch the settings for the app via this:

```
 UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (results) in
    ...
     })
```